# Change Interpreter in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to change the interpreter path of my Jupyter notebook environment to the interpreter path I am using with PyCharm.

When I execute the following code with Jupyter notebook I am getting the python installation within the Anaconda main folder and not the one I am using with PyCharm.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

With which command I can change the path to the other python installation I am using with PyCharm?

Answer (score 25):

I believe what you are looking for is how to change the Kernel you are running. If you go to the Kernel menu in Jupyter, you will see the option to change kernels.

[image]

If you want to add a new kernel from a conda environment, terminate jupyter, activate the environment you want to add a kernel for, and then run  this command (requires `conda install ipykernel` -- thx @shad):

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name <kernel_name> --display-name "<Name_to_display>"
```

Make sure to replace `<kernel_name>` and `<Name_to_display>` to the name of your environment. Also, this requires you to `conda install ipykernel` (thanks @shad).

Once you installed the kernel, you can change to it through the above menu and even through this code snippet from a Jupyter cell:

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.session.restart({kernel_name: '<kernel_name>'})
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I had to run this first: conda install ipykernel

Comment: I don't understand what I have to put in <kernel_name>, the path to the interpreter?

Comment: @user8635948 These instructions helped me: [link](https://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove) - It seems you can choose both names arbitrarily. To get the python binary you want, run the command DanielSchneider posted from that binary.

Comment: What if my primary Jupyter is in E: and I want to use a Python interpreter from a venv in drive E:?

Answer (score 0):

Activate first the env you want to use:

```
conda activate myenv
```

Then start jupyter afterwards:

```
jupyter notebook /path/to/your/dir
```

Comment: This changes the path where jupyter panel opens

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the following:

```
conda activate base
```

then check the location of the **jupyter** using

```
type jupyter
```

if it is located in

> ~/anaconda3/bin/jupyter

then you are good to go.
After that, you can use the **jupyter**
The one I use with my ssh-tunneling between my host and server machines is:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=1234
```