# Installed packages are not importing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, module, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am trying to import numpy module in jupyter notebook but it is giving me error as
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

I have numpy installed in my system as when I import the same in IDLE/Pycharm, it gets imported without any error and I am able to use it.
I tried

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/users/user/appdata/local/programs/python/python38/lib/site-packages')
import numpy as np
```

but it is showing error as
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

Comment: Are you certain Jupyter is using the Python you think it is?

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono it's showing python 3 and thus am not certain that whether it's using 3.7 or 3.8 as I have both in my system and numpy is installed for 3.8. Will you please tell that how should I check /change my project interpreter in jupyter.

Comment: It's addressed pretty well here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook I imagine that's the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Interpreter in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook)