# Jupyter interpreter permanently changed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, interpreter

I was playing around with a new library which setup a new venv and interpreter (python 3.8) to the following location.

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

```
'/Users/User/tensorflow_macos_venv/bin/python'
```

While this was fine when I had activated the venv, once I deactivate it and run the Anaconda3 jupyter notebook again, I still see the same interpreter. Could someone help explain how to can I revert it back to the original? I tried going to the "change kernel" option ([as mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook)) but I only see one option "python 3" there.

Just to clarify, in the terminal it still shows the default interpreter to be the correct one -

```
$which python
$/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

More importantly, is there a way I can have both available through the notebook options as it should be (in change kernel option)

Edit: I am using a mac and not Windows or linux.
Edit: It seems I had overwritten the interpreter path for the `Python 3` kernel with the new venv interpreter path. I have mentioned the steps I have followed to fix this below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent some time researching and found a way to fix the issue and add multiple kernels to the notebook. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, however, this could help others facing the issue.

```
$which python
$/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

The above command shows the default interpreter of the system however, Jupyter notebook gets its selected interpreter from a `connection file` which it reads during runtime. Its can be found here but the file itself is not important -

```
from jupyter_client import find_connection_file
find_connection_file()
```

```
'/Users/User/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-b1fa5520-5ae5-431a-8768-4ab4b755829f.json'
```

What is important is the location, since this connection file refers to the available `kernel.json` files which actually store the details about the interpreters available to jupyter notebook.

This location is under the same path as - `'/Users/User/Library/Jupyter/kernels'`

Here you will find a folder for each available interpreter (by default only a single folder). Inside the folder (usually called python3), you will find the `kernel.json`

> In my case, it should have looked like below. However, the path for mine was incorrect. I changed it back to the path to my default system python as below and it fixed my first issue of getting back to the original interpreter -

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/bin/python",  #<------ fixed this
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

**Next was adding another interpreter to the jupyter notebook**

If you have another interpreter which you want to add to the selection of kernels (Menu > Kernel > Change Kernel), then all you need to do is -

1. create a new folder in `'/Users/User/Library/Jupyter/kernels'`
2. copy the above `kernel.json` inside it
3. modify the path and the display name

In my case, I made the following -

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/Users/User/tensorflow_macos_venv/bin/python",  #<---- changed this
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "tf_mac",  #<---- changed this
 "language": "python"
}
```

Once done, you can check your available kernels using -

```
!jupyter kernelspec list
```

```
Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/User/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
  tf_mac     /Users/User/Library/Jupyter/kernels/tf_mac
```

This means that now you can go into the jupyter notebook menu Kernels > Change Kernels and find the above 2 kernels to switch between on the fly.

That's how I solved the above issue. Open to better methods because I am sure there would be.