# Fixing Anaconda Python after Big Sur update

Tags: python, anaconda, macos-big-sur

I recently upgraded macOS from High Sierra to Big Sur. My Anaconda installation, which was previously installed in `/anaconda3` is now broken.

First `/anaconda3` is missing; I found it in `/System/Volumes/Data/anaconda3`. Second, the `conda` and `activate` commands do not work because many files in the `anaconda3` folder still expect the path to be `/anaconda3`. For example,

```
$ /System/Volumes/Data/anaconda3/bin/conda env list
-bash: /System/Volumes/Data/anaconda3/bin/conda: /anaconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What's the solution to get this working on Big Sur? Should I nuke the `anaconda3` folder and re-install? If so, can I export the list of environments and packages to re-create them post-install?

Note that a similar issue affecting Catalina users is not identical to this Big Sur issue. If you didn't previously keep `anaconda3` under `/`, you can easily move the `anaconda3` directory back to its previous location. If `anaconda3` was under `/`, however, this is not possible because macOS Big Sur doesn't allow the folder to be put back under `/` even when using `sudo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda not found after upgrading to macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291108/conda-not-found-after-upgrading-to-macos-catalina) That is, this sounds identical to the Catalina upgrade issue Anaconda users hit.

Comment: @merv, the issue is similar, but not identical. The Catalina solution applies when `anaconda3` was previously in the home folder. Here, `anaconda3` was previously under `/` and macOS Big Sur doesn't allow the folder to be put back under `/`.

Comment: I think the point is that MacOS 10.15+ doesn’t allow root level folders. And that was the issue that Anaconda team acknowledges in the blog post. Instead, one can move the folder to under user home then use the `cpr` tool to repair dynamic library paths.

Comment: Do check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949574/jupyter-interpreter-permanently-changed/64949909?). This would give you some clarity on how to find out whats going on.

Comment: @ChrisP Did you manage to find a solution to this issue? I am experiencing the same after updating from Mojave to Big Sur and can't uninstall the folder following instructions elsewhere.

Comment: @rockdoctor, I never found a good solution. I ended up deleting the old `/System/Volumes/Data/anaconda3` folder (use `sudo` as needed) and re-installing. This worked, but required re-creating my environments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into several problems with conda after upgrading to Big Sur 11.4. I tried many proposed solutions you can find out there but none of them worked.

```
conda info
conda create --name=name_of_env
conda install whatever_package
```

All above commands just kept hanging and worked only in *safe mode*, even after several re-install and reboot actions.

What worked in the end was using `pyenv` to install anaconda.

```
pip install pyenv
pyenv install anaconda3-2021.05
```

After that things worked again.