# Set the Kernel Programmatically in a Jupyter Lab Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Can the kernel of Jupyter Lab be changed (set) programmatically inside a Jupyter lab notebook cell?
If so, how?

The alternative way is to use the Graphical User Interface of the Jupyter lab to change the lab from Kernel menu.

Comment: See the answers to [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook).  Does this work for you?

Comment: No @Frodnar, I receive Javascript Error: Can't find variable: Jupyter.

Comment: Do you use a programming language such as Python, or are you looking for a solution that would work when writing a JupyterLab extension?

Comment: I use. python inside the Jupyter notebook.