# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

so, i was trying to import cv2 to my jupyter notebook.

but it said

ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import cv2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

i already installed it using the command : pip install opencv-python
I'm on MacOS Catalina, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one python version installed? If so, make sure you are using the python interpreter you think you use for your notebook.
Run

```
!pip freeze
```

in your notebook to check if opencv-python is really listed as an installed package.
if not install it for that version or

[Change Interpreter in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: It is installed, still not importable.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem when installing opencv using conda and troubleshooted this by adding kernel manually as described in this page https://www.programmersought.com/article/97466914065/

The following are adaptations from the above-mentioned page:

1. First install ipykernel

   > conda install ipykernel
2. Add kernel manually

   > python -m ipykernel install --name stm32 --display-name "stm32h7"

Now, install cv2 again and inside the Jupyter Notebook, activate the `stm32h7` kernel by clicking on `Kernel --> Change Kernel --> stm32h7`. Now, try to import `cv2` again.