# Can't import a installed package in Python with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-packaging, copula

I have a strange problem. I want to use the package "copulas" in Python (https://sdv.dev/Copulas/). For that I first install it by using

```
!pip install copulas
```

The output is

```
Requirement already satisfied: copulas in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly<6,>=5.10.0 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from copulas) (5.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1.23.3 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from copulas) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy<2,>=1.9.2 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from copulas) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.5.0 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from copulas) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.5.0->copulas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.5.0->copulas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.5.0->copulas) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity>=6.2.0 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from plotly<6,>=5.10.0->copulas) (8.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from plotly<6,>=5.10.0->copulas) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\wi9632\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas>=1.5.0->copulas) (1.16.0)


[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then I check if it was installed by using the following code:

```
!python --version
!pip list
```

Which leads to the output:

```
Python 3.11.3
Package         Version
--------------- -------
copula          0.0.4
copulas         0.10.0
numpy           1.26.4
packaging       23.2
pandas          2.2.0
pip             22.3.1
plotly          5.19.0
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2024.1
scipy           1.12.0
setuptools      65.5.0
six             1.16.0
tenacity        8.2.3
tzdata          2024.1


[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

When I then try to import the module by using the code:

```
# import all relevant libraries
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pickle
import copulas
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-cec22cbc11bb> in <module>
      7 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      8 import pickle
----> 9 import copulas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copulas'
```

Here are some additional information:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

leads to the output:

```
['C:\\Users\\wi9632\\bwSyncShare3\\Eigene Arbeit\\Code\\Python\\lademodellierung-main', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\python39.zip', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\DLLs', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\lib', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39', '', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\wi9632\\.ipython']
```

and

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

Leads to the output:

```
'c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39\\python.exe'
```

Can you tell me, why I can install the library but not import it?

Comment: The issue is that you are installing the packages in python 3.11 but then your notebook is using python 3.9, so not the one where you installed it. Do you need python 3.9 or can you uninstall it? What are you using for running the notebook? Not conda I guess, is it vscode?

Comment: If you need python 3.9 you can go in `c:\\users\\wi9632\\python\\python39` and try to use the pip that should be in that folder

Comment: @bona_rivers: Thanks bona for your comments. Actually, I don't know what is used for python as this is neither my computer nor my script (but I need to run it on this computer). There is an anaconda version but when I click on it, windows tells me that it is deleted. I just start jupyther notebook by using a desktop shortcut

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook I think this can be of help. However this was for conda, so I'm not sure it will work, but try to look if you can select the python 3.11 in the kernel, maybe you have to install jupyter notebook with pip first

Comment: In 2019 the magic install command was added. You should be using `%pip install copulas` inside a running notebook to make sure that things are installed to where the kernel associated with your running `.ipynb` file. See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). As you've found, using the exclamation point in association with an install will install things but not necessarily to the correct location. Use this as a gauge for evaluating how current advice is that you find.

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks for your comment. Actually using the %pip installer I can import the package. However, on some other parts of the codes it can't find the imported packages anymore altough I clrearly imported them. I think something is wrong regarding the python version that is used. Somehow jupyter notebook seems to switch between different python versions and directories in my case because for some cells it shows different locations of the interpreter or uses different interpreters

Comment: My first priority was pointing out you were using outdated approaches for installing packages from inside a running notebook and that could be contributing. On top of that it may be that you messed up your Python installation along the way. That is sort of separate because you cannot correct that from inside the active running kernel. I think if you look into this more that is why a) it is historically difficult for Python/Jupyter users on windows who don't use package managers or virtual environments b) it is best on any system to be using a software manager like Anaconda/conda or ...

Comment: <continued> virtual environments to control where what gets installed better. Although the latter options do require learning more about tech that a lot of users find a challenge because of that initial bit of extra hurdle.

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks a lot for your comments. I really appreciate it. I just got a python script that includes the packages mentioned in my question and I just want to run it. What is the easiest way to do so? I just need to run it and not adjust it (and later on I will not need them any more). So I am looking for a method with as less effort as possible. What would you suggest

Comment: How demanding computationally are they? If they aren't that demanding you can use MyBinder.org. (The developers were apparently exploring the use of [that service here](https://github.com/sdv-dev/SDV/commit/d92797ad6eae9437fcf12ed2760cf0251e7e174e).) If they are demanding, then install [the Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download) on your own machine and make an environment and install the needed packages there. ...

Comment: <continued> Or do the similar thing on a remote cloud machine that you SSH tunnel into, such as via [Anaconda AMI on AWS](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/working-with-conda/applications/launch-ec2-ami/). Or use Linux on your own Windows machine via Windows Subsystem for Linux and work there.

Comment: Process to demonstrate copulas package working via MyBinder: Click [here](https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/HEAD?urlpath=%2Ftree%2F) and when the session comes up, click on the 'New' drop down on the right side to open a new notebook with the 'Python 3(ipykernel' option. When that opens, enter in the first cell `%pip install copulas`. Run that command and when it completes successfully, restart the kernel. Then step through pasting in and running the code under ..

Comment: <continued>  the example [Univariate Usage Example](https://sdv.dev/Copulas/tutorials/02_Univariate_Distributions.html#Univariate-Usage-Example). (I stopped trying the code upon reaching the 'Probability Density' section. )The plots will actually work and display, unlike in the current documentation. You should be able to use that as a guide to how you can run your code. You'll need to install each package the way I did for `copulas`. If you are using a script, you can paste in the code via the Jupyter dasboard (where you selected 'New' earlier) and then save the `.py` file. You can then...

Comment: <continued> run the saved script from your notebook by entering something like `%run my_script.py` and executing the cell. Substitute `my_script.py` for the actual name. You can also open a terminal and should be able to type `python my_script.py`. Running it in the notebooks will allow you more possibility to explore especially if you run it with the interactive flag (`-i)`, like `%run -i my_script.py`. That runs the script in the same namespace as the the initiating notebook. It's useful for developing the script further or troubleshooting it, see more about the -i flag ...

Comment: <continued>  [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks Wayne for your many comments and explanations. What I actually want to know what is the easiest way to run a jupyter notebook file with some given imported modules?

Comment: "I just got a python script that includes the packages mentioned in my question and I just want to run it. What is the easiest way to do so?" Your latest comment seems at odds with that previous comment. ... Anyway... I listed several ways to run Jupyter already in my comments. Then you install the necessary packages and open the `.ipynb` file and run it. I stepped through how to use copulas in a notebook fie. Not sure what else you are asking at this point? There's a lot of ways to get started with Jupyter and plenty of places ready to offer you what you need. Google Colab is another popular.

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks a lot for your tremendous help. I will have a closer look at them.

Comment: I should have added that if this for academic research-related purposes there's also some other options that I know of for harnessing remote machines. My `.edu` email is in my GitHub account (see my profile on StackOverflow) if you want to coordinate getting more information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are installing on a different version of Python than you are using. The version that has the package is 3.11.3, and the one you are activating is 3.9.
You can install in 3.9 version using `pip3.9 install copulas`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I don't know if I should use python 3.11.3 or python 3.9 and actually I don't care, the script should just run. But still I don't understand why the commands on the very same notebook use different folders?

Comment: How can I make every install, import and run command be realted to the same folder and interpreter in jupyter notebook. Somehow it uses different folders for the different tasks.

Comment: You can use a virtual env for this purpose. Try to follow these steps: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-jupyter-notebook-in-virtual-environment/

Comment: Thanks Magaren for your answer. Is there an easier way of doing this? I just want to run the script and ideally not set up anything

Comment: Could you describe exactly the scenario you have? I didn't understand why not configure the suggestion given

Comment: Thanks for your answers and effort. What I actually want to know what is the easiest way to run a jupyter notebook file with some given imported modules?